# Why is generics not seeing my inheritance?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

This is the code I'm using and it's having build error on instantiation.  I'm not sure why it's not seeing that my SpecialHandler is of type BaseHandler with T set as SpecialEntity

```
static class HandlerFactory
{
    public static BaseHandler<BaseEntity> Create(string typeString)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static BaseHandler<T> Create<T>(string typeString )  where T : BaseEntity {
        if (typeString == "Special")
            **return new SpecialHandler();** //THERE'S BUILD ERROR HERE EVEN THOUGH Special Handler is inherits from type BaseHandler<T>
        else
            return null;
    }
}

public class BaseHandler<T>  where T : BaseEntity
{
    public T GetEntity()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class SpecialHandler : BaseHandler<SpecialEntity> {}

public class BaseEntity{}

public class SpecialEntity : BaseEntity{}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is and what the question means?

Comment: Please describe the behavior your are observing.

Comment: Great pure code. if people tend to say please post code also, it doesn't mean that the description is not needed.

Comment: Sorry, for bad post.  I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Using my psychic debugging skills to infer the question)

Unless specified (and it works only on interfaces, anyway), the genetic parameter is invariant, i.e. exact.
A collection defined as a `List<Mammal>` is not in any way related to a collection defined as `List<Animal>` or to a collection defined as `List<Cat>`.

The `Create` method says that it returns a `BaseHandler<BaseEntity>`, not a `BaseHandler<SpecialEntity>`, and your `SpecialHandler` is-a `BaseHandler<SpecialEntity>`, but it is not a `BaseHandler<BaseEntity>`.

Comment: Spectacular psychic debugging skills :)

Comment: Thanks SWeko.  Your explanation was easy to understand... and you have good psychic skills as well :)